# Border radius en la parte superior de una tabla

Tags: css

Estoy creando una tabla y quiero que, exclusivamente, la parte superior de mi tabla tenga el efecto de la propiedad `border-radius`, es decir, tanto en la esquina superior izquierda como en la derecha. No entiendo por qué no se está aplicando la propiedad indicada. Sospecho que es por los diferentes bordes que definí. ¿Qué podría modificar para lograr lo deseado?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Localidad</th>
        <th>Años</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Daniel</td>
        <td>Colorado</td>
        <td>27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Maine</td>
        <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>Rhode Island</td>
        <td>57</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Karen</td>
        <td>Washington DC</td>
        <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>Pennsylvania</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gregor</td>
        <td>Virginia</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Derek</td>
        <td>Minnesota</td>
        <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rosa</td>
        <td>Arizona</td>
        <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jessie</td>
        <td>Connecticut</td>
        <td>41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Emma</td>
        <td>Michigan</td>
        <td>36</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #f4f8f9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #f4f8f9 0%, #5991da 100%);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}    


table tr th {
    background-color: #192D57;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #0d475c;
    
  
}

th, td {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #6383C8;
    color: #323770;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al utilizar border-collapse la propiedad border-radius no hace nada, como podrás ver en el siguiente link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/, una opción es reemplazarlo por border-spacing: 0 y luego haciendo usos de los childs seleccionar específicamente el elemento cuyo vértice se desea redondear y finalmente aplicar la propiedad correspondiente.

Podría ser útil algo así:

```
  table {
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #f4f8f9 0%, #5991da 100%);
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

table tr th {
  background-color: #192d57;
  color: #fff;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #384a6e;
  color: #2a2f68;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

table:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
table:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```